# Why is the leading white space gone?

Tags: bash

```
s="abc =    test"                                                           
s=${s#*=}
echo $s
```

It output `test` without the leading white space,

why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't quote the argument to `echo`, so it is subject to [word splitting](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/wordsplit), which happens *after* [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe).

```
echo "$s"
```

will include the spaces in the output.

Comment: Why is it gone if I don't quote it?

Comment: @new_perl: Because of *word splitting*.  Follow the above link for more details.

Comment: Will white space in the  end also be splitted?

Comment: @new_perl: Whitespace at the end will be stripped.  (How about just trying?)

Comment: @new_perl: You could redirect the output to a file.  Or just copy and paste the console window contents to a file.  (If you don't even know what difference it makes, why do you want to know?  Just wondering...)